# Matplotlib ScalarMappable returning only black color

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to create many plots. The plots involve making many FancyBboxPatches and setting the color for each patch using a ScalarMappable. Each plot corresponds to a "time step" from a physical process. I have made the following minimal working example to illustrate what I am trying to do and the problem I am having.

Suppose there is a file `data.txt`. If a line has one entry, that value is the time step. If a line has three entries, then the first entry is the x value, the second entry is the y value, and the third entry is the value that will use the ScalarMappable. Here is an example of `data.txt`:

```
1
0   0   0.1
0   1   1
0   2   2
0   3   3
0   4   4
1   0   10
1   1   11
1   2   12
1   3   13
1   4   14
2   0   20
2   1   21
2   2   22
2   3   23
2   4   24
3   0   30
3   1   31
3   2   32
3   3   33
3   4   34
2
1   0   10
1   1   11
1   2   12
1   3   13
1   4   14
2   0   110
2   1   111
2   2   112
2   3   113
2   4   114
3   0   120
3   1   121
3   2   122
3   3   123
3   4   124
4   0   130
4   1   131
4   2   132
4   3   133
4   4   134
3
2   0   110
2   1   111
2   2   112
2   3   113
2   4   114
3   0   1110
3   1   1111
3   2   1112
3   3   1113
3   4   1114
4   0   1120
4   1   1121
4   2   1122
4   3   1123
4   4   1124
5   0   1130
5   1   1131
5   2   1132
5   3   1133
5   4   1134
4
3   0   1110
3   1   1111
3   2   1112
3   3   1113
3   4   1114
4   0   11110
4   1   11111
4   2   11112
4   3   11113
4   4   11114
5   0   11120
5   1   11121
5   2   11122
5   3   11123
5   4   11124
6   0   11130
6   1   11131
6   2   11132
6   3   11133
6   4   11134
```

Here is the script I use to generate the plots:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch

def parse_file(file_name):

    output = {}

    with open(file_name, 'r') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            entries = line.strip().split()
            if len(entries) == 1:
                time_step = int(entries[0])
                output[time_step] = {}
            elif len(entries) == 3:
                x = float(entries[0])
                y = float(entries[1])
                value = float(entries[2])
                output[time_step][(x, y)] = value
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Anomalous line {} in file {}'.format(line, data_file.name))

    return output

def main():

    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    axes.set_xlim(-1,10)
    axes.set_ylim(-1,10)

    cmap = cm.plasma
    norm = LogNorm(vmin = 1e-2, vmax = 1.2e4)
    smap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = cmap)
    smap.set_array([])
    color_bar = fig.colorbar(mappable = smap, ax = axes, orientation = 'vertical', label = 'label')

    data = parse_file(file_name = 'data.txt')

    for time_step, information in data.items():
        cells = []
        for (x,y), value in information.items():

            cell = FancyBboxPatch(xy = (x - 0.5, y - 0.5),
                                  width = 1, height = 1,
                                  boxstyle = 'square,pad=0.',
                                  edgecolor = 'black',
                                  facecolor = smap.to_rgba(value))

            #print(time_step, '\t', x, '\t', y, '\t', value, '\t', smap.to_rgba(value))

            axes.add_patch(cell)
            cells.append(cell)

        fig.savefig('time-step_{}.png'.format(time_step))

        for cell in cells:
            cell.remove()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is one of the plots that is created from running that script:

[image]

This plot (and the other three that are created, but not shown here) look fine. So I am confident that I am using ScalarMappable correctly. Now I take the actual data I want to plot, again in a file called `data.txt`. The format is the same as before, except if a line has four entries, then the first entry is the time step (and I do not care about the other entries). Here is an example of `data.txt`:

```
     2    0.424066E-02    0.200000E+01    0.885500E+08
  0     1    0.850703E+00
  1     3    0.388551E-09
  2     4    0.141948E-06
  2     6    0.126299E-09
  3     9    0.166871E-08
  4    12    0.340738E-08
  5    13    0.246948E-09
  5    14    0.129005E-09
  6    16    0.140043E-08
  6    17    0.885307E-09
 26    76    0.591676E-08
 26    78    0.745985E-08
 27    77    0.263136E-08
 27    78    0.131857E-08
 27    79    0.151193E-05
 27    80    0.265941E-07
 27    81    0.170975E-05
 27    82    0.206355E-08
 27    83    0.334444E-07
 28    80    0.569439E-05
 28    81    0.864904E-07
 28    82    0.114196E-02
 28    83    0.130067E-06
 28    84    0.608045E-04
 28    85    0.351649E-07
 28    86    0.543117E-07
 28    88    0.202115E-08
 29    83    0.225374E-07
 29    84    0.125586E-07
 29    85    0.253383E-04
 29    86    0.943810E-06
 29    87    0.104539E-04
 29    88    0.210241E-06
 29    89    0.196533E-03
 29    90    0.707278E-06
 29    91    0.565096E-05
 29    92    0.840856E-08
 29    93    0.277478E-07
 30    86    0.707234E-09
 30    88    0.549048E-07
 30    89    0.281776E-08
 30    90    0.259219E-04
 30    91    0.298973E-06
 30    92    0.311047E-04
 30    93    0.144465E-05
 30    94    0.632642E-04
 30    95    0.787893E-08
 30    96    0.252900E-08
 31    91    0.425350E-08
 31    92    0.371105E-08
 31    93    0.621869E-05
 31    94    0.680069E-06
 31    95    0.315149E-04
 31    96    0.670790E-07
 31    97    0.568911E-06
 31    98    0.187946E-08
 31    99    0.135024E-07
 32    94    0.384693E-09
 32    96    0.174407E-06
 32    97    0.480216E-08
 32    98    0.244989E-05
 32    99    0.876257E-07
 32   100    0.189371E-04
 32   101    0.264917E-06
 32   102    0.297745E-05
 32   103    0.213684E-09
 33    99    0.110356E-08
 33   100    0.131345E-08
 33   101    0.448076E-06
 33   102    0.106369E-06
 33   103    0.128984E-04
 33   104    0.230382E-07
 33   105    0.266535E-07
 34   102    0.428166E-08
 34   103    0.668242E-08
 34   104    0.842244E-05
 34   105    0.843016E-07
 34   106    0.137510E-05
 34   107    0.879097E-08
 34   108    0.758233E-07
 35   105    0.280844E-06
 35   106    0.639110E-07
 35   107    0.497335E-05
 35   108    0.260105E-06
 35   109    0.188060E-05
 35   110    0.375853E-09
 35   111    0.935430E-09
 35   112    0.138533E-07
 35   113    0.101658E-06
 35   114    0.504823E-09
 35   115    0.989704E-09
 35   116    0.152468E-06
 35   117    0.220735E-07
 36   114    0.430884E-08
 36   116    0.115980E-07
 36   117    0.128436E-05
 36   118    0.814433E-05
 37   117    0.316595E-09
 37   118    0.141531E-06
 37   119    0.965141E-05
 38   119    0.459954E-08
 38   120    0.114088E-04
 38   121    0.198695E-09
 39   120    0.109457E-08
 39   121    0.105160E-04
 39   122    0.254984E-08
 40   122    0.717566E-05
 40   123    0.179081E-08
 40   124    0.352463E-09
 41   123    0.454357E-05
 41   124    0.629608E-07
 41   125    0.777480E-07
 42   124    0.453866E-05
 42   125    0.108592E-06
 42   126    0.320262E-06
 42   127    0.252596E-09
 42   128    0.114714E-09
 43   125    0.372578E-06
 43   126    0.344297E-07
 43   127    0.188018E-05
 43   128    0.631276E-08
 43   129    0.368003E-08
 44   126    0.170090E-07
 44   127    0.121695E-07
 44   128    0.147407E-05
 44   129    0.349674E-07
 44   130    0.767494E-06
 45   128    0.193141E-09
 45   129    0.361851E-06
 45   130    0.573704E-07
 45   131    0.457287E-06
 45   132    0.148004E-08
 45   133    0.164772E-07
 45   134    0.386942E-09
 45   135    0.539603E-08
 45   136    0.227778E-09
 45   137    0.640126E-08
 45   138    0.189604E-09
 45   139    0.754561E-09
 46   132    0.215880E-07
 46   134    0.102847E-08
 46   136    0.628736E-08
 46   137    0.427124E-09
 46   138    0.711664E-07
 46   139    0.749082E-08
 46   140    0.425043E-06
 46   141    0.776307E-08
 46   142    0.102985E-06
 46   143    0.693232E-09
 46   144    0.215846E-08
 47   141    0.660244E-08
 47   142    0.901189E-09
 47   143    0.299062E-07
 47   144    0.195833E-08
 47   145    0.178405E-07
 47   146    0.558550E-09
 47   147    0.235167E-08
 48   144    0.393065E-09
 48   146    0.493252E-08
 48   147    0.299176E-09
 48   148    0.130504E-07
 48   149    0.244654E-09
 48   150    0.143702E-08
 49   149    0.565286E-09
 49   151    0.122230E-08
     3    0.424066E-02    0.200000E+01    0.885500E+08
  0     1    0.850710E+00
  1     3    0.388551E-09
  2     4    0.141948E-06
  2     6    0.126299E-09
  3     9    0.166871E-08
  4    12    0.340738E-08
  5    13    0.246948E-09
  5    14    0.129005E-09
  6    16    0.140043E-08
  6    17    0.885307E-09
 26    76    0.593799E-08
 26    78    0.747463E-08
 27    77    0.283934E-08
 27    78    0.115725E-08
 27    79    0.153613E-05
 27    80    0.236099E-08
 27    81    0.171178E-05
 27    83    0.334426E-07
 28    80    0.575684E-05
 28    81    0.242170E-07
 28    82    0.114208E-02
 28    83    0.133947E-07
 28    84    0.608362E-04
 28    85    0.335522E-08
 28    86    0.543624E-07
 28    88    0.202170E-08
 29    83    0.258149E-07
 29    84    0.107337E-07
 29    85    0.261133E-04
 29    86    0.167223E-06
 29    87    0.108977E-04
 29    88    0.432469E-08
 29    89    0.196993E-03
 29    90    0.997563E-08
 29    91    0.565922E-05
 29    92    0.127589E-09
 29    93    0.277365E-07
 30    86    0.731139E-09
 30    88    0.613936E-07
 30    89    0.984612E-09
 30    90    0.261316E-04
 30    91    0.845314E-07
 30    92    0.324848E-04
 30    93    0.656773E-07
 30    94    0.632706E-04
 30    95    0.335583E-09
 30    96    0.252938E-08
 31    91    0.529954E-08
 31    92    0.394099E-08
 31    93    0.681605E-05
 31    94    0.104800E-06
 31    95    0.315602E-04
 31    96    0.231610E-08
 31    97    0.566868E-06
 31    99    0.135330E-07
 32    94    0.450380E-09
 32    96    0.178679E-06
 32    97    0.955313E-09
 32    98    0.252946E-05
 32    99    0.770340E-08
 32   100    0.191937E-04
 32   101    0.825856E-08
 32   102    0.297762E-05
 33    99    0.128999E-08
 33   100    0.146516E-08
 33   101    0.616111E-06
 33   102    0.539415E-07
 33   103    0.128046E-04
 33   104    0.865090E-09
 33   105    0.266759E-07
 34   102    0.899336E-08
 34   103    0.331924E-08
 34   104    0.850733E-05
 34   105    0.462457E-08
 34   106    0.137714E-05
 34   107    0.199044E-09
 34   108    0.758844E-07
 35   105    0.308602E-06
 35   106    0.470668E-07
 35   107    0.520013E-05
 35   108    0.458893E-07
 35   109    0.185756E-05
 35   111    0.159320E-07
 35   112    0.729552E-09
 35   113    0.101697E-06
 35   114    0.135746E-09
 35   115    0.128676E-06
 35   116    0.231448E-07
 35   117    0.220783E-07
 36   114    0.480979E-08
 36   116    0.921582E-06
 36   117    0.373798E-06
 36   118    0.814449E-05
 37   117    0.888355E-08
 37   118    0.132905E-06
 37   119    0.965147E-05
 38   118    0.360663E-09
 38   119    0.423745E-08
 38   120    0.114090E-04
 39   120    0.109122E-08
 39   121    0.105186E-04
 40   122    0.717737E-05
 40   124    0.352428E-09
 41   123    0.460618E-05
 41   124    0.358205E-09
 41   125    0.777514E-07
 42   124    0.464136E-05
 42   125    0.589035E-08
 42   126    0.320503E-06
 42   128    0.114709E-09
 43   125    0.408148E-06
 43   126    0.567978E-08
 43   127    0.187958E-05
 43   129    0.368007E-08
 44   126    0.258868E-07
 44   127    0.348446E-08
 44   128    0.150718E-05
 44   129    0.167101E-08
 44   130    0.767515E-06
 45   128    0.176686E-09
 45   129    0.403334E-06
 45   130    0.162718E-07
 45   131    0.458273E-06
 45   132    0.196826E-09
 45   133    0.167474E-07
 45   135    0.563904E-08
 45   137    0.655709E-08
 45   139    0.751998E-09
 46   132    0.216010E-07
 46   134    0.107901E-08
 46   136    0.673825E-08
 46   138    0.784839E-07
 46   139    0.220743E-09
 46   140    0.432287E-06
 46   141    0.427029E-09
 46   142    0.103696E-06
 46   144    0.211976E-08
 47   141    0.696394E-08
 47   142    0.585710E-09
 47   143    0.315456E-07
 47   144    0.425448E-09
 47   145    0.181981E-07
 47   146    0.136911E-09
 47   147    0.226765E-08
 48   144    0.442465E-09
 48   146    0.553370E-08
 48   147    0.138932E-09
 48   148    0.128376E-07
 48   150    0.144107E-08
 49   149    0.624360E-09
 49   151    0.123765E-08
```

The script that I use to create the plots is almost the same as before. The only differences are (1) how `data.txt` is parsed, (2) setting the limits of the x and y axes, and (3) the variable `norm`. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.patches import FancyBboxPatch

def parse_file(file_name):

    output = {}

    with open(file_name, 'r') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            entries = line.strip().split()
            if len(entries) == 4:
                time_step = int(entries[0])
                output[time_step] = {}
            elif len(entries) == 3:
                x = float(entries[0])
                y = float(entries[1])
                value = float(entries[2])
                output[time_step][(x, y)] = value
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('Anomalous line {} in file {}'.format(line, data_file.name))

    return output

def main():

    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    axes.set_xlim(0,150)
    axes.set_ylim(0,250)

    cmap = cm.plasma
    norm = LogNorm(vmin = pow(10, -10), vmax = pow(10, -2.2))
    smap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = cmap)
    smap.set_array([])
    color_bar = fig.colorbar(mappable = smap, ax = axes, orientation = 'vertical', label = 'label')

    data = parse_file(file_name = 'data.txt')

    for time_step, information in data.items():
        cells = []
        for (x,y), value in information.items():

            cell = FancyBboxPatch(xy = (x - 0.5, y - 0.5),
                                  width = 1, height = 1,
                                  boxstyle = 'square,pad=0.',
                                  edgecolor = 'black',
                                  facecolor = smap.to_rgba(value))

            #print(time_step, '\t', x, '\t', y, '\t', value, '\t', smap.to_rgba(value))

            axes.add_patch(cell)
            cells.append(cell)

        fig.savefig('time-step_{}.png'.format(time_step))

        for cell in cells:
            cell.remove()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now all of the patches are black. Here is one of the plots that is created:

[image]

I do not see anything obviously wrong using the print statement (which is commented out in the script):

```
print(time_step, '\t', x, '\t', y, '\t', value, '\t', smap.to_rgba(value))
```

Why are all the FancyBboxPatches black instead of the color I have chosen with the ScalarMappable (and how can I make them be the color I have chosen with the ScalarMappable)?

Comment: Yes! You are exactly correct about the size! Thank you! I'm not sure how I accept a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look as if the patches are black. I would guess that they are just too small, such that their edge (which is black) takes up the complete area of the patch. You may use a thinner edge, or no edge at all, or you may set the edgecolor to the value of your liking as well. In general, You may also use simple patches like Rectangle instead of the FancyBboxPatch.